# Copy Alternating Lines Into Blanks In Between

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a macro which takes a spreadsheet in which there is a row of data and then a blank row. The macro copies some of the data from the first row into the second row. To accomplish this, it looks at a field which includes data whenever a row will need to be copied (cut really), if the check cell is not empty, it cuts data further into the row and pastes to the row below.

[image: The data before the macro.]

When I run the macro, it correctly cuts and pastes several rows of data and then it switches to cutting blank cells and overwriting data.

[image: Data after running the macro.]

This is intended to be part of a larger macro which, among other things, inserts the blank lines. When this error cropped up, I broke it out into two steps, which is why there are extra variables defined. Inserting the blank rows is working fine. I then saved the data as a csv to clear any formatting from the first macro and ran the second. The code I'm working with is as follows:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'

Dim iCounter As Long
Dim LastRowColumnB As Long, NewLastRow As Long
    LastRowColumnB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    NewLastRow = LastRowColumnB + LastRowColumnB
    Dim MyRange As Range, NewRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("B2:B" & LastRowColumnB)
    Set NewRange = Range("B2:B" & NewLastRow)
 With ActiveSheet
        For Each Row In NewRange
            If IsEmpty(Row.Cells(10)) Then
                Range(Cells(Row.Row, 16), Cells(Row.Row, 25)).Cut Destination:=Range(Cells(Row.Row + 1, 6), Cells(Row.Row + 1, 15))
            End If
            MsgBox ("Pause")
        Next Row
    End With
    
End Sub
```

I have tried running as both If and If Not IsEmpty. When run as an If Not, no cells are cut and pasted correctly, but good data gets overwritten starting where it changes when run as an If. I have also tried data sets of different length. There is no obvious connection between how many rows are treated correctly (e.g. it being related to the initial number of rows before the insert macro runs.)

Obviously, the message box is just added to make the program run one row at a time for diagnostic purposes.

Comment: Shouldn't `For Each Row In NewRange` be `For Each Row In NewRange.Rows`? Anyway it's faster to work with arrays instead of ranges.

Comment: Your cut paste is triggered if the check cell is empty.  Based on your description I would expect it to trigger when the cell is not empty?

Comment: HannahW: I found that loop here on Stack Overflow. I would have thought the same as you, but it seems to work correctlier as I have it, in that it starts working correctly. When I run it as an If Not, it starts copying blank lines over data with the second data row and then, with the same pair where it switches as above, it simply cuts blank cells to blank cells.

Evil Blue Monkey: Adding .Rows doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code with my corrections:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim LastRowColumnB As Long
    LastRowColumnB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("B2:B" & LastRowColumnB)

    Dim tmpRow As Range
    
    For Each tmpRow In MyRange.EntireRow
        If IsEmpty(tmpRow.Cells(11)) Then
            Range(Cells(tmpRow.Row - 1, 16), Cells(tmpRow.Row - 1, 25)).Cut _
            Destination:=Range(Cells(tmpRow.Row, 6), Cells(tmpRow.Row, 15))
        End If
    Next tmpRow
End Sub
```

Here is my suggested way to do it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim LastRowColumnB As Long
    LastRowColumnB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("B2:B" & LastRowColumnB)

    Dim tmpCell As Range
    
    For Each tmpCell In MyRange.Cells
        If IsEmpty(tmpCell.Offset(0, 10)) Then
            tmpCell.Offset(0, 4).Resize(1, 10).Value = _
            tmpCell.Offset(-1, 14).Resize(1, 10).Value
        End If
    Next tmpCell
    
    Set MyRange = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Jim Becker. That does the trick.